# How to find unique string from a semicolon separated map keyset?

Tags: apex, trigger, map, collection

I have a mapElement which is of type **Map<string,List< product2>>**. The key part contains semicolon seperated values.It contains values like

**(catA;catB;catC; , Prod A )

(catD;catE;catA; , Prod B )

(catA;catB; ,Prod C )

(catD;catE; , Prod D )**

....
so on

The requirement is that I have to find a commmon element in the key set to which I can associate maximun no of product.From the above example
it will be like a map forming below

**(catA,{Prod A,Prod B,Prod c})**
 in which 3 products can be associated and **Prod D** can ne associated with either **catD** or **catE** like 
 **(catD,{Prod D})** or
 **(catE,{Prod D})**.

Help appreciated.

I tried to form a set of string with all the key elements like setA=**{catA,catB,catC,catD,catE}**
 and tried to iterate over the map. But it is not giving desired results.

```
Map<string,List<QuoteLineItem>> mapUniqueEuipType = new Map<string,List<QuoteLineItem>>();
    
Set<string> uniqueEquipType=new Set<string>();
integer dripCount=0;
integer espCount=0;
integer speCount=0;
system.debug('mapMultiEuipType : handleMultipleEquipType '+mapMultiEuipType);
for(string strEquipMulti:mapMultiEuipType.KeySet())
{
    for(string strItr:strEquipMulti.split(';'))
    {
        if(!uniqueEquipType.contains(strItr))
        {
            uniqueEquipType.add(strItr);
        }
    }           
    
}
if(uniqueEquipType.size()>0)
{
    system.debug('uniqueEquipType list :'+uniqueEquipType);
    for(string uniqueTypeSet:uniqueEquipType)
    {
        system.debug('uniqueEquipType 334 :'+uniqueTypeSet);
        for(string strEquipMulti:mapMultiEuipType.KeySet())
        {
            system.debug('strEquipMulti 336 :'+strEquipMulti);
            if(strEquipMulti.contains(uniqueTypeSet))
            {
                system.debug('strEquipMulti contains Drip');
                if(uniqueTypeSet.equalsIgnoreCase('DRIP'))
                    dripCount++;
                else if(uniqueTypeSet.equalsIgnoreCase('Espresso'))
                    espCount++;
                else if(uniqueTypeSet.equalsIgnoreCase('Specialty'))
                    speCount++;
            }
        }
        
    }
}
System.debug('Drip Escp spe :'+dripCount+'#'+espCount+'#'+speCount);
if(dripCount==mapMultiEuipType.size())
{
    List<QuoteLineItem> lstitemsFlat=new List<QuoteLineItem>();
    for (List<QuoteLineItem> collection : mapMultiEuipType.values())
        lstitemsFlat.addAll(collection);
    mapUniqueEuipType.put('DRIP',lstitemsFlat);
}
// 
if(espCount==mapMultiEuipType.size())
{
    List<QuoteLineItem> lstitemsFlat=new List<QuoteLineItem>();
    for (List<QuoteLineItem> collection : mapMultiEuipType.values())
        lstitemsFlat.addAll(collection);
    mapUniqueEuipType.put('Espresso',lstitemsFlat);
    
}

if(speCount==mapMultiEuipType.size())
{
    List<QuoteLineItem> lstitemsFlat=new List<QuoteLineItem>();
    for (List<QuoteLineItem> collection : mapMultiEuipType.values())
        lstitemsFlat.addAll(collection);
    mapUniqueEuipType.put('Specialty',lstitemsFlat);
    
}

return mapUniqueEuipType;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, although more roundabout than I would write, your existing code gets it more or less correct until you hit the final 3 if blocks like this one `if(dripCount==mapMultiEuipType.size())`

If my reading is correct, then `mapMultiEquipType.size()` is going to be the size of your starting map. That information is not going to be of any use to you here (you'd only "flatten" a given product if it appeared in all of the values for all keys in `mapMultiEuipType`).

It should be possible to shorten this code significantly. I don't see a reason why you couldn't just build your "flattened" map in the first nested for loop. The key here (no pun intended) is that you still have access to the "combined"  key from the outer loop inside of your inner loop.

You should be able to use that to populate the lists you're storing by individual keys.

```java
// I believe this is the only collection you need (aside from the input)
Map<String, List<QuoteLineItem>> mapUniqueEuipType = new Map<String, List<QuoteLineItem>>();
    
for(string combinedCategory :mapMultiEuipType.KeySet()){
    for(string individualCategory :combinedCategory.split(';')){
        // This is a common pattern for building Maps, and it works particularly
        //   well when the value type is a non-primitive type (like a List)
        // By initializing the value here, we can avoid the need to do any
        //   additional checks and keep repeated code to a minimum
        if(!mapUniqueEuipType.containsKey(individualCategory)){
            mapUniqueEuipType.add(individualCategory, new List<QuoteLineItem>());
        }

        // Breaking this onto multiple lines to make my explanation easier to digest.
        // This could be done on a single line
        // First, we get the List stored in the new Map
        mapUniqueEuipType.get(individualCategory)
            // This gives us a reference to a List, which we can call .addAll() on
            //   (or .add() if your input map is a Map<String, QuoteLineItem> instead
            //   of a Map<String, List<QuoteLineItem>>)
            .addAll(
                // Every item referenced by the combined category key needs
                //   to be put into the list for each individual key
                mapMultiEuipType.get(combinedCategory)
            );
    }
}
```

At the end of the first iteration of the outer loop, mapUniqueEuipType should look like

```
{
    'catA' => [Prod A],
    'catB' => [Prod A],
    'catC' => [Prod A]
}
```

Since the key for 'catA' already exists, on the second iteration of the outer loop, we should simply add to the existing list. The other two split keys would generate new lists, and you should end up with

```
{
    'catA' => [Prod A, Prod B],
    'catB' => [Prod A],
    'catC' => [Prod A],
    'catD' => [Prod B],
    'catE' => [Prod B]
}
```

and in the end, this iterative build approach should give you the result you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you @derek